# NTRUencrypt in NIST competition

Tags: public-key, nist, ntru

Why did the NTRUencrypt team not maintain the NTRU1024 release in the NIST second-round competition?

Is this because of the speed performance or security performance or other things?

Comment: Hello, Hassan. Someone made the same question on PQC forum and got [this answer](https://groups.google.com/a/list.nist.gov/forum/#!topic/pqc-forum/j2yEYU_isxo). Maybe you could read it then edit your question to highlight what is not clear there and which additional information you are seeking...

Comment: Hello, Victor. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered [on the PQC forum](https://groups.google.com/a/list.nist.gov/g/pqc-forum/c/j2yEYU_isxo). The question was asked by El Hassane Laaji:

> Hello NTRU team
>
> Can you say me, why you didn't keep the NTRUencrypt-1024 release, is it because of speed performance or security performance.
>
> Best regards.

The reply came from John Schanck:

> Thanks for your question. To clarify for others, the "NTRUencrypt-1024"
> parameter set was proposed in the first round NTRUEncrypt submission for
> use with the ss-ntru-pke and ss-ntru-kem schemes. I'll split your question
> into two parts:
>
> - Why didn't we recommend ss-ntru?
> - Why didn't we recommend an NTRU variant that uses Z[x]/(x^1024 + 1)?
>
> Regarding ss-ntru:
>
> At a fixed security level, NTRU and LWE schemes have a trade-off
> triangle between
>
> 1. the correctness of the decryption procedure,
> 2. the width of the coefficient distributions,
> 3. the compactness of public keys and ciphertexts.
>
> The second round NTRU team wanted a compact scheme with a correct
> decryption procedure. The coefficient distribution used in ss-ntru
> is not compatible with that goal.
>
> Regarding Z[x]/(x^1024 + 1):
>
> It's not clear to us that there's a real need for an NTRU parameter set
> with such a large n. The largest n that we recommend is 821.
>
> Best,
> John (on behalf of the NTRU team)